# Entity Framework ISNULL in Where condition

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, isnull

I have a Query in SQL Server :

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable t
WHERE ISNULL(t.Status,'') = ''
```

How I can do it in Entity Framework?

EDIT:
Oh Sorry my code was like

```
WHERE ISNULL(t.Status,'') = ''
```

Comment: You just need `WHERE t.Status = 'CO'`. The `ISNULL` does not affect the semantics and makes it unsargable.

Comment: @MartinSmith yeah I understand that but I mistakenly submitted the question as WHERE ISNULL(t.Status,'') = 'CO', Actually it was WHERE ISNULL(t.Status,'') = ''

Comment: That's still unsargable. You should just use `WHERE t.Status = '' OR t.Status IS NULL`

Comment: I am not working with SQL Statement. I just used it as an example here. I needed Entity Framework statement. I got it. Anyhow Thanks.

Comment: Granted this is useless in a `WHERE` clause, but it's mighty handy in `ORDER BY` where `NULL` should be treated as greater-than-anything-else.  Since googling the general question of "EF SQL isnull()" (and probably variants) gives this as a top result, I'll throw in my +1 to balance the scales.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try something like

MyTable.Where( t => (t.Status ?? "") == "CO" )

Comment: This WHERE t.Status = 'CO' should be fine. Why you need to check for ?? (null) ?

Comment: Although it is unnecessary to do so, it is what the OP requested. I don't think it generates `ISNULL` but `COALESCE(...)` but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: It's to guard against NULL propagation. In this example the OP could get away with it, but it just seems like better practice.

Comment: It is definitely not better practice. It can convert an efficient seek into a full table scan. Unfortunately [Code analysis rule SR0007](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7471822/73226) does (or at least did) recommend it which is maybe why the OP has it.

Comment: It's not the best for fast results, that's true.  But, null propogation in unexpected places can mean broken results.  The real fix is to not use NULLs on searchable columns.

Comment: The real fix is to understand the technologies you are using. Three valued logic is not difficult to get to grips with.

Comment: Null is not a value, but the absence of one.

Answer (score 6):

Although the question is ok, the logic isn't sound.
Because if a value is equal to `CO`, it can never be equal to either `NULL` or `''`.
In this case you could just easily call it like this:

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable t
WHERE t.Status = 'CO'
```

Linq:

```
var items = (from t in db.MyTable
             where t.Status == "CO"
             select t);
```

However if you would need it to have a default value when `NULL` and compare to that value it would make more sense (see example):

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable t
WHERE ISNULL(t.Status, 'CO') = 'CO'
```

Linq:

```
var items = (from t in db.MyTable
             where (t.Status ?? "CO") == "CO"
             select t);
```

This would give you all items where t.Status is `NULL` or equal to `CO`.
This is, of course, just an example.

Note: The generated sql would probably be slightly different, but the result is the same.
It would probably look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable t
WHERE COALESCE(t.Status, 'CO') = 'CO'
```