# Linq to entities if in select statement

Tags: sql, vb.net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have this linq query

```
Dim chiamateAperte = From statoRic In
                                    dbVulcano.StatoRic.Where(Function(s) s.RFStato >= 11 And s.RFStato <= 13 And s.Attuale = 1 And s.RFTecnico = rfTecnico)
                                 From richiesta In
                                    dbVulcano.Richieste.Where(Function(r) r.IDRic = statoRic.RFRic).DefaultIfEmpty()
                                 From cliente In
                                    dbVulcano.Clienti.Where(Function(c) c.IDCliente = richiesta.RFCliente).DefaultIfEmpty()
                                 Select statoRic.ID, statoRic.RFRic, statoRic.RFStato, statoRic.Attuale, richiesta.Descr, cliente.RagSociale, statoRic.DataAss, statoRic.Data, dataf = If(statoRic.DataAss.HasValue, statoRic.DataAss, statoRic.Data), statoRic.OraDalle, statoRic.OraAlle
                                 Order By dataf Descending, statoRic.OraDalle Ascending
```

It's working fine but I want to add an order condition on "OraDalle" field.
OraDalle it's sort of a time field, but sadly on db it's defined as smallInt (and I cannot change it), so the format is like "800" to say "eight o'clock". This field can be null.
So instead of statoRic.OraDalle I tried this:

```
orad=if (statoRic.OraDalle.HasValue,statoRic.OraDalle,2359)
```

And then

```
Order By dataf Descending, orad Ascending
```

But it throws an ugly error: cannot cast system nullable 1 to system object of type 'system.nullable'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Then I tried this:

```
orad=statoRic.OraDalle.GetValueOrDefault(2359)
```

But it also throw an error like: linq to entities does not recognize the method 'Int16 GetValueOrDefault(Int16)'

So... how can I achieve what I want? This whole mess is to get a list ordered by time, where null time values are at the bottom (and not on the top, as default). Thank you all!

Comment: try `if (statoRic.OraDalle,2359)`. This should be the equivalent of C#´s `statoRic.OraDalle ?? 2359` which was the accepted answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20687076/2882256) question.

Comment: So simple! You're my hero! :-D

Comment: You may want to accept my answer if you´d like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `if (statoRic.OraDalle.HasValue,statoRic.OraDalle,2359)` use `if (statoRic.OraDalle,2359)`

This is the equivalent of C#´s null-coalescing-operator `??`:
`statoRic.OraDalle ?? 2359` which was the solution for a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20687076/2882256).