# Is comparing against nulls defined behavior?

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, where-clause, sql-null

In a recent code review, I was asked to change

```
Amount > 0
```

to

```
ISNULL(Amount,0) > 0
```

Is there a chance these might right different results? From what I can tell, they would both return false if Amount is null or 0 and true in any other case

To give further details, I want to get all rows in one table, as long as they do not have a corresponding row in a second table with an amount > 0

```
-- Get members that do not have unpaid fees
Select m.Name from Members m
left join Fees f on m.Id = F.memberId and F.AmountDue > 0
where F.memberId is null
```

Comment: Try `NOT (Amount > 0)` to realise that comparison against `NULL`s doesn't return `FALSE`.

Comment: It is dangerous to make broad statements about snippets of code and a lack of context. But you are incorrect in one way - if amount is NULL the result of the expression is UNKNOWN, not FALSE. Is that significant? Impossible to say without context.

Comment: See [Three-valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic) which does contain a specific section on SQL

Comment: Did you ask the reviewer why you have to change it?

Comment: HB makes a good point. A code review is an educational tool as well as a correctness tool. If someone suggests you change something and you don't understand, you should ask questions. And if someone is making a suggestion, that suggestion should be offered with solid reasons why it is an "improvement".

Comment: Is Fees.Amount a nullable column? If not (and I doubt it should be) the suggestion is pointless. And to be honest, I cannot see why that column would allow anything but a value > 0.

Comment: @SMor See my update.  It is a nullable column (which doesn't have any null values in the actual table)

Comment: They might be basing this on something like [code analysis rule SR0007](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7471740/73226) unfortunately that rule is bad advice.

Comment: If your requirement (as appears in comment) is "do not have unpaid fees", then the condition "AmountDue > 0" will meet that requirement if that is the correct logic. Any value that is null will be ignored in the same manner as any value <= 0.

Comment: As a rule, injecting _magic values_ is a bad thing. Using `( Amount > 0 or Amount is NULL )` is clear. The problem arises when the _magic value_ starts to have a special meaning, e.g. when `Amount = 0` means "complimentary subscription". Suddenly some innocent code that used that value breaks when the meaning changes from "unlikely value" to "specific peculiar meaning". Then someone decides `-1` means a left-handed subscriber and ... . Aside: Curious that you join on `F.memberId` and then use `where F.memberId is null` to filter the results.

Comment: @HABO I'm filtering on f.memberId is null because I *don't want* any results with corresponding entries

Answer (score 2):

`amount > 0` checks if `amount` is stricty greater than `0`. If the value is `NULL`, the condition returns `unknown` (which is not `true`, but actually other than `false`)..

`ISNULL(amount, 0) > 0` does the same thing. `NULL` values are turned to `0`, which also fails the check - however in that case `false` is returned instead of `unknown`.

Depending on what you want to do with the result of the condition, both conditions may or may not behave identically. If you use that in a `where` clause for example, there is no notable difference. However the second condition is less efficient, since it requires additional computing, and is likely to not be able to take advantage of an existing index on `amount`, if any.

Comment: @Kevin: ok. Well, for your query, there is no advantage in using `ISNULL()` (and it makes the code less efficient, as explained). I wouln't use it in that context.

Comment: Comparing to NULL returns UNKNOWN, not NULL. [A boolean datatype](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/comparison-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) has only 3 possible values: TRUE, FALSE, UNKNOWN

Answer (score 0):

Comparing anything to NULL results in UNKNOWN rather than FALSE.

This does essentially have the same effect as returning false in that the query will only return rows where the amount is not null and greater than 0 but you should be careful not to assume that when amount is null the result of the comparison is false

For example this will also fail to return null rows :

```
WHERE NOT(amount > 0)
```

`amount > 0` is UNKNOWN not FALSE. If it were false then NOT would turn it true

You could conceive that NULL is a contaminant that makes its way all the up through every Boolean condition and operation it touches, turning them all UNKNOWN and then "becomes false" right at the very last moment because the final assessor of the Boolean predicate demands a TRUE

By and large you can consider UNKNOWN as synonymous with NULL; UNKNOWN is relatively confined to Boolean logic. In other contexts such as mathematical operations involving NULL results in null (0+NULL = NULL). The only operation that can work on null and produce a Boolean is `amount IS [NOT] NULL`

---

Per your code review, if they're going to insist on a blanket "must coalesce any value that might be null" It would appear that the business rule is that the system is intolerant of nulls – in this case it should be that the column is made not null and filled only with actual values. Passing any value through a function that may or may not change it cripples the use of indexes and introduces problems for query planning. One could hope that a smart optimizer could expand/rewrite `ISNULL(amount, 0) > 0` to `amount > 0 or (amount is null and 0>0)` before simplifying to remove the bracketed condition entirely but it's not necessarily always that simple. Better not to feed crap in in the first place than shrug and go "well it doesn't seem to make things slower in my simple test case"

Applying a blanket rule without any thought or justification could lead to a very poorly performing system. How you will feed this back to the people who make the rules could be s difficult office politic to handle, because their approach is wrong but they're unlikely to admit it or want to be told

---

As an aside you might feel that the equivalent query better captures the notion of what you're trying to do:

```
SELECT m.Name 
FROM Members m
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 
  FROM Fees f 
  WHERE m.Id = F.memberId and F.AmountDue > 0
)
```

The left anti join pattern is a favourite of mine for all sorts but I do feel that this is more self explanatory - "all members that don't have a related record where they owe money". NOT IN also makes this quite readable but should be used with care as some database implementations can be quite naive:

```
SELECT m.Name 
FROM Members m
WHERE NOT IN (
  SELECT F.MemberId 
  FROM Fees f 
  WHERE F.AmountDue > 0
)
```

SQL server will highly likely rewrite a LEFT JOIN WHERE NULL/WHERE NOT EXISTS/WHERE NOT IN so they're planned and executed identically, but you might find there isn't much appreciation of this/dim view of the IN approach at the next code review :)

Comment: I added some details/context to question

Comment: Comparing anything to NULL does not return NULL - that is just incorrect no matter how many edits. Comparing to NULL returns UNKNOWN.

Comment: @SMor I've always felt that's a matter of semantics rather than an appreciable technical difference but I appreciate we're striving for precision here. In terms of memory load for developers I've always felt  it's probably better to keep to a tri state logic they already grok and carry a notion they probably already appreciate (0+null=null) into the realm of comparison, than to introduce a fourth element and discuss UNKNOWN as if it's somehow behaviorally different to NULL in other operations.